# I have a folder named sampledata with 4 excel files .I want to read content of each excel file

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a folder named sampledata with 4 excel files (ie, 'b.xlsx', 'call.xlsx', 'Daily.xlsx', 'Whatsapp metadata.xlsx'). I want to read content of each excel file in python.

Can anyone help me?

`fi` contains path for each file.

```py
import os
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
path='/Users/user78/Downloads/references/forensic/sampledata/'
root,dir,files=next(os.walk(path),[])
print(files)
excel_count=0
text_count=0
excel_files=[]
text_files=[]
for file in files:
    fi=os.path.join(root,file)
    print(type(fi))
    print(fi)
    with open(fi,'r') as f:
        workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(f)
        sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        for i in range(sheet.ncols):
            print(sheet.cell_value(0,i))
```

Above is my code and the resulting error is given below.

```
['b.xlsx', 'call.xlsx', 'Daily.xlsx', 'Whatsapp metadata.xlsx', '~$call metadata.xlsx', '~$Whatsapp metadata.xlsx']
<class 'str'>
/Users/user78/Downloads/references/forensic/sampledata/b.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user78\Downloads\references\forensic\sample.py", line 28, in <module>
    workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(f)
  File "C:\Users\user78\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 110, in open_workbook
    filename = os.path.expanduser(filename)
  File "C:\Users\user78\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ntpath.py", line 312, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if you can use pandas , refer [pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), `pd.read_excel('yourFile.xlsx')`

Comment: XLRD package is for reading data and formatting information from older Excel files (ie: .xls), `"This library will no longer read anything other than .xls files. For alternatives that read newer file formats, please see http://www.python-excel.org/."`

Comment: pandas works for me

Answer (score 1):

`xlrd.open_workbook()` expects a filename as the first parameter, not an already opened file as in your case. Try `xlrd.open_workbook(fi)` and remove the with-context.

The [XLRD-Pypi-page](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) contains a simple example code for reference.

However as already mentioned by Shijith and also clearly stated in the library's description, XLRD should only be used for the "old" excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using **Pandas.read_excel()**

**Code Structure**

> *According to **[pandas.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)***

```
pandas.read_excel(io, sheet_name=0, header=0, 
names=None, index_col=None, usecols=None, 
squeeze=False, dtype=None, engine=None, 
converters=None, true_values=None, false_values=None, 
skiprows=None, nrows=None, na_values=None, 
keep_default_na=True, na_filter=True, verbose=False, 
parse_dates=False, date_parser=None, thousands=None, 
comment=None, skipfooter=0, convert_float=True, 
mangle_dupe_cols=True, storage_options=None
```

**Code Syntax**

```
import pandas as pd

b_df = pd.read_excel('sampledata/b.xlsx')
b_df_lidt = b_df.to_list()    # if you want to convert the data into list.

call_df = pd.read_excel('sampledata/call.xlsx')
call_df_list = call_df.to_list()

....
```